# c# webclient select sql string

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14b1c/0)** for reference and Schema of table

I'm using a WebClient to read an write an remote db (MySql v5.5).
I'm trying to use this query to write in a table :

```
 string query "INSERT INTO ProgettoGruppi (`id`, `progettoID`, `gruppoID`, `orePreviste`, `oreAttuali`, `stato`) VALUES (NULL, 1, 2, 0, 0, 'test3')"
```

this is the answer from my DB :

**"Database access failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'test3\')' at line 1"**

If I replace 'test3' with NULL it work fine.

wich is the correct format to write 'test3' in the string?

this is the code that i'm using:

```
string PASSWORD_STRING = "&password=xxx";
string USER_STRING = "?user=xxx";
string query1 = "INSERT INTO ProgettoGruppi (`id`, `progettoID`, `gruppoID`, `orePreviste`, `oreAttuali`, `stato`) VALUES (NULL, 1, 2, 0, 0, 'test3')";
string query2 = @"&query=" + query1;
byte[] responseArray = threadClient.DownloadData(@"http://www.xxxxxx.it/getDataFromMySql.php" + USER_STRING + PASSWORD_STRING + query2);
```

this is the PHP code used:

```
$c_query = $_GET['query'];
$tSql = $c_query;
$result = mysql_query($tSql)
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
    $Filed[$j] = mysql_fetch_row($result);
}
$json_string = json_encode($Filed); 
echo $json_string ;
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: It seems that 'stato' doesn't accept string. What type of field is?

Comment: What is the type of `stato` column?

Comment: Sorry gian74, bit _It doesn't work_ is the most unhelpful statement that could be written on this site. Please be more precise. Do you get an error message? If yes what is the message? In which code the line above is used?

Comment: @Steve I'm using MySql 5.5

Comment: So the problem is the column `Stato`, you try to write a string in it. This means that your datatable column is of type text, if not then the error is here. Is `stato` used as some kind of flag and wants a number instead of a string?

Comment: @tezzo the type of 'stato' is text

Comment: @Steve the answare from Db is **"Database access failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\'test3\\')' at line 1"**

Comment: Can you post your table schema on sql fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: It seems that there is some error in you string query not apparent from the line above. Could you post the exact code that you are using?

Comment: @SurajSingh [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14b1c/0)

Comment: I am not sure that this could be your problem, but worth a try. Remove the backticks around your field names. They are not needed in this context and I am not sure if they could be a problem in the query received by the backend

Comment: @Steve I removed the backticks but nothing change. If I use this query I have no problem **INSERT INTO ProgettoGruppi ( progettoID, gruppoID, orePreviste, oreAttuali, stato) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, NULL)**

Comment: I can only say that the C# side of the query is correct. Also, if you try to run it in Fiddle and then do a select * from ProgettoGruppi, the row with ID=11 is correctly added. So I can only conclude that there is a problem in the `getDataFromMySql.php` page

Comment: But steve sql fiddle runs code even if we have declared `stato` as NOT NUll and insert NULL values. Can we rely on fiddle every time ?-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52e09e/1

Comment: @steve I updated my answer with the php code

Comment: @gian74 add the PHP tag also to see if someone expert on that find something wrong in your PHP code

Comment: It seems like sending a SQL query to a PHP page like this is a bad idea. The user could run anything they wanted to using this approach. Make sure your PHP page is secured, not allowing arbitrary SQL to be run, and make sure that the queries you run are using a different account than your MySQL root account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on the php code (how supposed by @steve)

I send this string from c#:

```
string query "INSERT INTO ProgettoGruppi (`id`, `progettoID`, `gruppoID`, `orePreviste`, `oreAttuali`, `stato`) VALUES (NULL, 1, 2, 0, 0, 'test3')"
```

in the PHP file I receive this string

```
"INSERT INTO ProgettoGruppi (`id`, `progettoID`, `gruppoID`, `orePreviste`, `oreAttuali`, `stato`) VALUES (NULL, 1, 2, 0, 0, \'test3\')"
```

I used **stripslashes()** in my PHP code to remove the slash.

thanks to all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your fields accepts NULL values, and every nvarchar field needs the '',
like for your 'test3', you maybe need to set '1', '2' etc.. if you are using nvarchar fields

otherwise, remove the 'id' field if not needed, and remove the NULL value